# Is there any rule that says that oxygen should have at least one free pair of electrons in Lewis dot structure?

Tags: physical-chemistry

For example, Ozone has a double and single bond with at least one free pair of electrons in each oxygen atom. My doubt is whether ozone can have a triple bond and single bond with one oxygen atom without a free pair of electrons.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{H4O^{2+}}$ is a counter example to such a rule.

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00265a031